# Jump to top of parent from iframe - cross domain

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe that is a bit long that I want to jump up to the top of the page once the submit button is pressed (I'm using ASP.NET and a new panel shows within the iframe once the form is submitted). The problem is my iframe is on a different domain than my parent page. Here's what I have so far:

In iframe:

```
<script>
function scrollWindow(){
        window.top.scrollTo(0,0);
}
</script>
<input type="submit" onclick="scrollWindow();" value="Submit Request">
```

This works if the parent and iframe are on the same domain, but not cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

If the page within the iframe is changing when you press submit you should be able to use the "onload" event of the iframe to trigger the scrolling.

It's a hack, and you should feel bad about doing it. It should work though.

Comment: I'm new to asp.net but I don't think it's reloading, I think its more like a new panel is showing when the button submit event is triggered.

Comment: If you can add a hash tag to the URL of the iframe from the inside you should be able to monitor the URL of the iframe from the outside using a busy wait. onLoad would have been much cleaner since it will be triggered once.

Comment: Wouldn't that reload the whole page? I want the thank you panel to show after it's submitted (which is in the same iframe doc). If I reload the page, won't the whole thing reload presenting the original form?